# SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync is lying to me

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication

I've been using this code to log in:

```
//
// GET: /Account/Login
[AllowAnonymous]
public ActionResult Login(string returnUrl)
{
    ViewBag.ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
    return View();
}

//
// POST: /Account/Login
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return View(model);
    }

    // This doesn't count login failures towards account lockout
    // To enable password failures to trigger account lockout, change to shouldLockout: true
    var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Email, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: false);
    switch (result)
    {
        case SignInStatus.Success:
            return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
        case SignInStatus.LockedOut:
            return View("Lockout");
        case SignInStatus.RequiresVerification:
            return RedirectToAction("SendCode", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl, RememberMe = model.RememberMe });
        case SignInStatus.Failure:
        default:
            ModelState.AddModelError("", Account.LoginFailure);
            return View(model);
    }
}
```

This is code that came with the Visual Studio MVC application template. It worked up until to day when all of the sudden it stopped working. I have debugged through this code `SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync` returns `Success` but on the following request, I am not logged in.

**Updates:**

I shelved all of my pending changes and I still cannot log in. I am the only one working on this code. It is not anything I am doing.

**Further Updates:**

This code works on my coworkers machine. It works when I post it to the staging server. It just will not work on my computer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first thing i did was delete "*.v12.suo" file. It didn't work. This time I first closed the solution, then deleted that file. Now it works. I can only shrug. This is a really frustrating problem. It magically works now. I hope someone can provide me with more understanding about this crazy situation.

Comment: I got this too just now on my production Azure site. It happens when I try to log in with the *.azurewebsites.net URL, but not with the mydomain.com domain that I assigned the site. This was working fine yesterday!

Comment: Windows Identity is a terrifying beast. I suspect there are only about two people in the world who understand it correctly (Hao Kung and Brock Allen) and everybody else is just trusting in the MS template code.

Comment: This is happening to me, but in reverse. It works fine locally, but not on my Azure Virtual Server. I connect to the process in VS2015 and see it make it to 'case SignInStatus.Success'... but my iOS app is still not logged in. And this worked fine before.

Comment: If this is affecting you on *.azurewebsites.net or 'in reverse', check out my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/40401289/529544 @spudnick

Answer (score 1):

Even though this post is old, i just had the same problem, so in the hopes that it can help someone i will post it.

I just had a similar problem, however i didn't test online, only local. I use Chrome as primary development browser. 
Long story short, i found that after i cleared every possibility from my password manager (Dashlane) everything worked fine. So for me it was some weird combination of clearing everything from the site, and clearing the passwords from my password manager.
Hope this helps someone in the future.

Comment: I am still having this issue with aspnetcore 2.0

I think i read somewhere that Chrome has a bug with storing cookies on localhost, but I haven't verified this,

Comment: Unfortunately this only helped me temporarily, however i have no problem when i uploaded it to the web. My advise is to use another browser locally.